# Stop Windows 10 detecting 2nd monitor if being used by another computer

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

This is a bit of an odd one as most problems are normally "windows cannot detect my monitor", however in this case it is detecting it when I dont think it should.

So I have 2 monitors a pc and a laptop, so connection wise its:

```
Monitor 1
| - PC DisplayPort 1

Monitor 2
| - PC DisplayPort 1
| - Laptop HDMI 1
```

If the laptop is nowhere to be seen both monitors work correctly being `Monitor 1` and `Monitor 2` on the PC. However the problem is introduced when we have both the laptop and the PC on at the same time, as then the laptop correctly takes `Monitor 2`, but the PC incorrectly thinks it is using both monitors.

I can see why its doing this as technically both monitors are on and the PC has a connection to both, however `Monitor 2` has a source button where I can tell it where it should be taking its source from, so when the laptop is on I just tell it to use `HDMI 1` but I was hoping windows would be clever enough to somehow know that the monitor is not actually using the signals it sends it.

So is there a way to get windows to factor in the source of the monitor?

Comment: No, Windows isn't that smart. And no, there's no work around.

Comment: It's working as designed, in fact. I use a similar system here & if it ever glitches & fails to see the 2nd monitor it totally messes up my workflow:\

Comment: So I can give the answer a reward can someone just put up that windows works this way and there is no work around and I will give the answer @GabrielaGarcia you had it first. Currently im just telling the PC to just use monitor 1 manually but was hoping there would be some form of workaround :(